# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 8 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, json, mysqli

this code is for my graph
the error is
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 8 column 1 of the JSON data

```html
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pos");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else
{
    $data_points = array();
    
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product");
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {        
        $point = array("label" => $row['product_name'] ,"y" =>$row['product_price']);
        
        array_push($data_points, $point);        
    }
 
    
    echo json_encode($data_points, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);


}
mysqli_close($con);

?>







<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
<script>
window.onload = function () {
 
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 exportEnabled: true,
 theme: "light1", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
 title:{
  text: "Simple Column Chart with Index Labels"
 },
 data: [{
  type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
  //indexLabel: "{y}", //Shows y value on all Data Points
  indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
  indexLabelPlacement: "outside",   
  dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
 }]
});
chart.render();
 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

json data
[{"label":"One Piece T-Shirt","y":300},{"label":"Plain Blue T-Shirt","y":250},{"label":"Polo Shirt","y":619},{"label":"Formal Long Sleeve","y":799},{"label":"Jordan","y":3999},{"label":"Black Shoes","y":450},{"label":"Nike Pink Rubber Shoes","y":2500},{"label":"Maroon Skirt","y":300},{"label":"Black Nike","y":3000},{"label":"Maong Short","y":300},{"label":"Navy Blue jogging pants","y":450},{"label":"Black jogging pants","y":450},{"label":"short maong short","y":250},{"label":"Black And White Skirt","y":445},{"label":"high heels sandals","y":700},{"label":"White Gold Sandals","y":750},{"label":"blue sleeve less","y":300},{"label":"green long sleeve","y":400},{"label":"crop top long sleeve","y":600},{"label":"Programmer Ring","y":999}]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wa9x4kfL/ I don't get an error, can you give steps to recreate/more info?

Comment: Could it possibly be all that non whitespace stuff that follows your json encoded output?  Your header declares json and then you add html about 8 lines later.

Comment: I don't get it , what should I do?
that code is for graph , recreate https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-column-chart/ code into a php mysqli